# Show $\mathbb F_{p}[x]/(x^{p}-1)$ is indecomposable as a representation of $\mathbb Z/ p\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, idempotents

Let $R=\mathbb F_{p}[x]/(x^{p}-1)$. $R$ has both ring and vector space structure. I am trying to show that, given a representation $\rho : \mathbb Z/ p\mathbb Z\rightarrow GL(R)$, any invariant subspace $V\subset R$ under the action of $\rho_{g}$ is indecomposable. That is, $\nexists W \subset R$ such that $R=V\oplus W$. I am also curious if I can write down all the invariant subspaces $V_{i}$ under $\rho$.

Here is what I have done so far:
I proved any intertwining map $T: R \rightarrow R$ is given by multiplication by some $r\in R$. I also proved that $(x-1)^p=x^p-1=0$ which implies that the minimal polynomial does not have distinct roots in $\mathbb F_{p}$. I am hoping to deduce that $u^2=u\space \forall u\ne 0,1$ in $R$ in order to show no nontrivial projection $R\rightarrow V$ exists, since intertwining maps are given by multiplication by elements of $R$. Hence, there is no decomposition.

Comment: By $GL(R)$ do you mean all $\mathbb F_p$-vector space automorphisms $R \to R$?  All ring automorphisms?  All $\mathbb F_p$-algebra automorphisms?  If I had to guess I'd say $GL(R)$ meant $\mathbb F_p$-vector space automorphisms.  In that case your statement is not true for all $\rho$.  We could take for example $\rho(x) = 1$ for all $x$.  Then $R$ would be completely reducible.  Is there a particular $\rho$ that you mean to choose?

Comment: @Jim: $\mathrm{GL}$ has a unique meaning, there is no need to guess. It is $\mathrm{Aut}_{\mathrm{Vect}}$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: This would not be the first time that I've seen $GL$ used for any of those alternative suggestions.  In general if a question is asking something that's trivially incorrect then it's perfectly reasonable to double check their meaning.